# Proving that $\vec F$ is conservative field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

> I need to prove that $\vec F$ is coservative field:

$$\vec F=\underbrace{\bigg(yz+\frac{1}{yz} \bigg)}_{Q} \hat i+\underbrace{\bigg(xz-\frac{x}{y^2z} \bigg)}_{P}\hat j+\underbrace{\bigg(xy-\frac{x}{yz^2} \bigg)}_R\hat k$$

**My attempt:**

$\vec F$ is conservative field iff $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial z}$

but $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} \neq \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

Comment: I think that the cross partial test only applies when you have a simply connected domain? However your $F$ is undefined if $y$ or $z$ are $0$. Instead try to exhibit a potential function. In particular you can try to integrate $Q$ with respect to $x$, which will be easy as it contains no $x$s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James said, you want to find a potential function.  A field $\vec{F}$ is conservative if it can be written as $\vec{\nabla}V$.  In that case you have 
$$ \vec{F} = P \hat{i} + Q \hat{j} + R \hat{k} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\hat{k}$$

The way you wrote the conservative field condition is wrong for the order of terms.  If defined $P$, $Q$, $R$ as here, the condition is $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, and is equivalent to requiring that 
$\tfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x \partial y} = \tfrac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y \partial x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$V(x,y,z)=xyz+\frac{x}{yz}$(+ a constant) is the potential $\Rightarrow$ the field is conservative.

Comment: @1999 It explains that the field is conservative. The question was about how to prove it. Besides, it provides with an alternative direction of thinking when solving such kind of problems, namely - if you manage to find a potential then you are done disregarding how you have found it.