# Proving that $\vec F=yz(2x+y+z)\hat i+zx(x+2y+z)\hat j+xy(x+y+2z)\hat k$ is conservative field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I need to prove that $\vec F$ is conservative field

> $$\vec F=yz(2x+y+z)\hat i+zx(x+2y+z)\hat j+xy(x+y+2z)\hat k$$

**My attempt:**
$\vec{F}$ is conservative iff $\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0$
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
&\hat i&\hat j &\hat k\\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
&yz(2x+y+z)&zx(x+2y+z)&xy(x+y+2z)
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$\color{blue}\Longrightarrow$

$$
=\begin{vmatrix}
&\hat i&\hat j &\hat k\\
&2yz&2xz&2xy\\
&yz(2x+y+z)&zx(x+2y+z)&xy(x+y+2z)
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$$=[x+y+2z-2]\hat i -[x+y+2z-2]\hat j +[x+2y+z-2]\hat k\color{red}{\neq 0}$$

> Where am I wrong?

Comment: When you set it up, you were fine, but I don't see how you got from the $\nabla\times\vec{F}$ to the thing after the blue implication arrow.

Comment: why not just find $U$ for which $\vec{F}= \nabla U$ then it is immediately true that $\nabla \times \nabla U=0$ and you have the potential to boot.

Comment: title already used  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360644/proving-that-vec-f-is-conservative-field

Comment: @janmarqz not anymore

Comment: Let $g_1(x,y,z),\  g_2(x,y,z),\ g_3(x,y,z)$ three functions of $x,y,z$. The point is that $$\left\vert\begin{matrix}\hat i&\hat j&\hat k\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ g_1&g_2&g_3\end{matrix}\right\vert\neq\left\vert\begin{matrix}\hat i&\hat j&\hat k\\\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial z}\\ g_1&g_2&g_3\end{matrix}\right\vert$$ and you calculated the second instead of the first.

Comment: I don't really understand how you came up with that sufficient and necessary condition for conservative fields...and less can I understand what you did afterwards. Perhaps this is a notation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have a 'potential'

$$
\phi = x^2yz + xy^2z + xyz^2
$$

so that

$$
\vec{F} = \vec\nabla \phi,
$$

whence

$$
\vec\nabla \times \vec{F} = \vec\nabla \times \vec\nabla \phi = 0,
$$

so it is conservative.

Answer (score 1):

It's just as easy to use the definition:

$\vec F$ is conservative $\Leftrightarrow $ there is a $\varphi :\mathbb R^{3}\to \mathbb R$ such that $\nabla \varphi =\vec F$. The method for finding $\varphi $ is straightforward and has the advantage that it is consistent; it will tell you if such a $\varphi $ exists.

If there is a $\varphi $ with the advertised property, then

$\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}=yz(2x+y+z)$ which implies that

$\varphi =yz(x^{2}+yx+zx)+g(y,z)$. Then,

$\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}=zx^{2}+2zxy+z^{2}x+\frac{\partial g(y,z)}{\partial y}$ and this must be equal to

$zx(x+2y+z)$ so that

$\frac{\partial g(y,z)}{\partial y}=0$. This means that

$g(y,z)=f(z)+c$ for some constant $c\in \mathbb R$. So we have, up to now

$\varphi =yz(x^{2}+yx+zx)+f(z)+c$ from which

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}=yx^{2}+y^{2}x+2zyx+f'(z)$ and this must be equal to

$xy(x+y+2z)$ so that

$f'(z)=0\Rightarrow f(z)=c_{1}$. Then, finally we have

$\varphi =yz(x^{2}+yx+zx)+C$ where $C=c+c_{1}$.